# Why LRU caches use doubly link list and not singly link list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, hashmap, lru

I have been trying to understand why LRU caches use doubly link list and not singly link list?

If i go by the time complexities they both have same for insertion , updation and deletion.
[Here is the Cheat sheet](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/)

Is it because the two ways pointers in DLL is used for easier move of nodes to rear or front ??

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-doubly-linked-list-used-in-LRU-Least-Recently-Used-implementation-as-in-this-link-Implement-LRU-Cache-GeeksforGeeks may help maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind LRU cache implementation using list (DLL/SLL) is to move the recently used page(node) to the front.

This involves a lot of shifting, say the node is in the middle of the list (DLL/SLL), you'd have to remove the node, rearrange the next pointer of the previous node.

Now in this case, if we use Singly Linked List we'd have to maintain the previous node of the most recently accessed node.

This operation is not necessary if we use Doubly Linked List as it already maintains the previous and next pointer.

The catch here is accessing that latest node, for which we use a hashtable giving us access to that node in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

To remove a targeted node from a linked list, you need to modify the other nodes that point to it.

In a doubly-linked list, the targeted node has pointers to these other nodes, so it's easy to find them.

In a single-linked list, the targeted node does *not* have a pointer to the other node that points to it.  You still need to modify that node, though, so you'd have to search for it.